# Problem merging Branch.io and Segment.io user's attribution data on Amplitude

Tags: branch.io, segment-io, amplitude-analytics

my company has an app developed using Ionic, and we use the JS version of the Segment library.

```
npm package ngx-segment-analytics
```

I'm trying to integrate attribution data on Amplitude, my data flow looks like this:

```
Facebook -> (MMP) Branch.io -> Amplitude
Google Ads -> (MMP) Branch.io -> Amplitude
User Engagement (App) -> Segment.io -> Amplitude
```

The problem is Amplitude is not able to match the user's entries, probably because Branch.io identifies the users with the IDFA and it seems like Segment.io JS library don't send IDFA data to its destinations. Then Amplitude don't even show de data, since it is stored for 72h and if not merged with an actual user event it is discarded.

What is the best way to make sure attribution data is properly merged in Amplitude? Is it possible to send IDFA data on track and identify calls context using Segment.io?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you let me know if you have enabled Amplitude as a DI partner from Branch Dashboard? We would automatically be sending all referred events to Amplitude.

Comment: Yes, we did enable the data feed to Amplitude. It seems like there is more than one problem. The first one is that Facebook is not sending all the Standard Events, but only the installs and clicks (no data on TrialStart, ViewContent, LevelAchieve) not to all the events we have mapped.

After that, it seems like none of them are getting to Amplitude, or being identified to an existing user.

Comment: Facebook attributed data would not be forwarded to Amplitude. Can you drop an email to support@branch.io?

Comment: Thank you @KartikShandilya, already did and figured it out.